# Android MediaPlayer SDK

Tags: android

I have a program with a function copied below it plays a sound upon clicking a button. If you click the button 10 times 10 different media players play the same sound that is the way i want it but how can i assign a button to stop all 10 media players at a time like a "STOP ALL BUTTON"

```
public void onClick(View v){
 int resId = 0;
 int stopped = 0;
 switch (v.getId()){
 case R.id.Wail:
  resId = R.raw.fedsigwail;
  break;
 case R.id.Yelp:
  resId = R.raw.fedsigyelp;
  break;
 case R.id.HiLow:
  resId = R.raw.hilow;     
  break;
 case R.id.FederalQ:
  resId = R.raw.federalq;
  break;
 case R.id.Horn:
  resId = R.raw.fedsignhorn;
  break;
 case R.id.STOPALL:
  mp.stop();
  mp.release();
  stopped = 1;
  break;
 }

 if (stopped != 1){
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
 mp.start();
 }


}
```

The code above only stops the last instance of mp.

Any Input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mp.stop();` only stops one instance of a media player, since mp can only be one mediaplayer instance.
If mp is one of your media players, where are the other ones? You mentioned you have

> 10 different media players

so I would expect something like mp1, mp2, mp3, ..., mp10. But right now it seems you actually only using one media player instance, or at least stopping it.

With each call of

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId)
```

you lose the reference to the previous created media player, since you 'override' it with a newly created instance.
You need to keep a reference to all your created media players, i.e. via an ArrayList or HashMap or similar.

Comment: So go with an Array of Media Player Objects

ie: MPArray[i] = MediaPlayer.Create(this, resId);
i++

then to kill all sounds

do a length on MPArray

then a for loop to go from 0 index to length index of the array can call stop on each for example MPArray[2].stop()?

Is that what you suggesting i do? or and i way overthinking it

Comment: i did it like this and got a force close i dont know where i went wrong.

public class Hello extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {

 int resId = 0;
 int status = 0;
 int mpindex = 0;
 
 private MediaPlayer mpArray[] = new MediaPlayer[999];

    public void onClick(View v){
     int resId = 0;
     int stopped = 0;

*** REMOVED SWITCH FUNCTION TO ASSIGN RESID DUE TO CHARACTER LIMIT. ***

// Create MediaPlayer instances 
      mpArray[mpindex].create(this, resId);
      mpArray[mpindex].start();
     }

When i click to play sound get force close

Comment: Force close: check the logfile (adb shell logcat) or logcat in Eclipse. btw: please add the code to your initial quesions, there it gets formatted and easier to read. In a comment it's hard to read.

Comment: Shouldn't the line to create the media player be like this: 
mpArray[mpindex] = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
otherwise you're not assigning anything to mpArray[mpindex]